# How do I use multiple pickers?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uipickerview, subview

My app collects various types of information and sends it off to our server. Some of the questions are of fixed type so I need to use Pickers. When I've used pickers before they are initialised when the app starts with the array of selections. I had thought I would use different pickers through various subViews. Would it be better to use just one Picker and then reset the array used dynamically. If so how do I do this?

Comment: you mean that loading same picker with different array on different event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each method of both the datasource and the delegate protocols contain a UIPickerView * parameter, for instance:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

You need to use it to distinguish between your two instances, as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
if([pickerView isEqual: pickerOne]{
  // return the appropriate number of components, for instance
     return 3;
}

if([pickerView isEqual: pickerTwo]{
  // return the appropriate number of components, for instance
     return 4;
}
}
```

Comment: Answer copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/768126/1228. Please read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Answer (score 0):

Give the two different tags. And compare tag for loading your array.